# Pascal's triangle faulty output

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, pascals-triangle

Hi I'm making an iterative Pascal's triangle in Java. So far everything works great, until number of rows exceed 13. The output becomes faulty. I must be doing something wrong here, please help.

IterativePascal:

```
public class IterativePascal extends ErrorPascal implements Pascal {
    private int n;
    IterativePascal(int n) throws Exception {
        super(n);
        this.n = n;
    }
    public void printPascal() {
        printPascal(false);
    }

    public void printPascal(boolean upsideDown) {
        if (n == 0) { return; }
        for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                System.out.print(binom(j - 1, i) + (j == i + 1 ? "\n" : " "));
            }
        }
    }

    public long binom(int n, int k) {
        return (k == 0 || n == k) ? 1 : faculty(n) / (faculty(k) * faculty(n - k));
    }

    private long faculty(int n) {
        if (n == 0 || n == 1) { return 1; }
        int result = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            result = result * i;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
1 5 10 10 5 1
1 6 15 20 15 6 1
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
1 10 45 120 210 252 210 120 45 10 1
1 11 55 165 330 462 462 330 165 55 11 1
1 12 66 220 495 792 924 792 495 220 66 12 1
1 4 24 88 221 399 532 532 399 221 88 24 4 1 <----- wrong
1 0 1 5 14 29 44 50 44 29 14 5 1 0 1 <----- wrong
```

Help would be appriciated, since I'm new with algorithms.

Comment: I'm sure that the *real* Einstein would not have called that "faculty" :-)   The word you or your spelling correction software are looking for is "factorial".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're reaching number overflow. Because `14!` is too big to fill in java `long`.

The solution will be to use `+` instead of `!`.

Keep your triangle as an 2D array and iterate through it. Each cell should be sum of two 'above'.

```
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 |   |   |   |
| 1 | 1 |   |   |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |   |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

The code will be as it follows:

```
public static void triangle(int n) {
    int[][] triangle = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        triangle[i] = new int[i+1];
    }
    triangle[0][0] = 1;
    triangle[1][0] = 1;
    triangle[1][1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        triangle[i][0] = 1;
        for (int j = 1; j < triangle[i].length - 1; j++) {
            triangle[i][j] = triangle[i-1][j] + triangle[i-1][j+1];
        }
        triangle[i][triangle[i].length-1] = 1;
    }
    printArray(triangle);
}
```

**Edit:**
As the OP requires recursive solution with binoms, I decided to add solution introducing `BigInteger`s as it might be the case.

```
public BigInteger binom(int n, int k) {
        return (k == 0 || n == k) ? BigInteger.ONE : faculty(n).divide((faculty(k).multiple(faculty(n - k)));
    }

private BigInteger faculty(int n) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    while (!n.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
        result = result.multiply(n);
        n = n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    }
    return result;
}

public void printPascal(boolean upsideDown) {
    if (n == 0) { return; }
    for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            System.out.print(binom(j - 1, i).toString() + (j == i + 1 ? "\n" : " "));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a recursive method, also containing long binom, which works fine. I really need to stick to my original code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to use binoms, simply switch from longs to `BigInteger`s. Remember, that you can calculate binom more eficiently. I mean, you shouldn't perform any divisions. Instead of calculating `n!/(k!(n-k)!` calculate `n*(n-1)*...*(k+1)/(n-k)!`. Still better than your code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in your computation of the factorial: I'd assume that your int type can hold numbers up to 32 bits, but 13! is larger than that.

You could check whether long can store larger numbers and define result as long.

Comment: When an excellent accepted answer already exists, try to make sure you have new information before answering (this answer is currently in the low quality queue)

Comment: maybe you should be really really sure about which answer was first before writing

Comment: You're right, sorry, I didn't notice the other answer was also recent. It's very common for a new user to answer old questions.

Comment: okay. nevertheless, your comment was also neither helpful nor friendly, so rather useless.